# Prevent code contract to display the precondition code

Tags: c#, code-contracts

```
Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type), "Type is required");
```

When I use the above statement in my method, and when the condition fails. Both precondition failure code and user message gets concatenated. And the output is like

> Precondtion failure !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type) Type is required

How can I get rid of the code which is getting printed? I just want user message to be displayed.

Comment: Do you mean that I modify the code like bool isValidType = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type) and then use Contract.Requires(isValidType, "Type is required");

Comment: I'm not sure why you want the error message to be *less helpful* (remember, these messages should never be visible to an end user as a contract violation is a coding error), but if you're using full Contracts, there's fine print in the manual about installing a custom handler for contract violations. You'll likely need that if you want the omit the condition. See chapter 7, "Runtime Contract Behavior" (in particular sections 7.2 and 7.4 on `ReportFailure` and `TriggerFailure`). Disclaimer: I've never used this capability.

Comment: Well, all contract errors are being displayed to the end user, that's why I wanted to prevent the actual code to be displayed. Do you have a link where I could check the "Runtime Contract Behavior"?

Comment: The manual is installed when you [install Code Contracts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RiSEResearchinSoftwareEngineering.CodeContractsforNET). Note: the direct link to the user manual on that site is broken, in that it doesn't actually give you the manual but just loops back to install instructions. Also, if you are not using the rewriter, I don't know if/how you can influence the runtime code behavior; you may just get the built-in behavior of the framework with no way to override.